# How is numpy.random.Generator different from RandomState?

Tags: python, numpy, random

`Generator` sounds like a replacement for `RandomState`, and the way of the future for generating random numbers in NumPy.

What features or behavior (currently or planned) does `Generator` have that `RandomState` doesn't?

Both can be parameterized with `BitGenerator` objects. They have some different methods, but the vast majority appear to be the same.

Relevant links:

- [docs on the "legacy" RandomState](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/random/legacy.html)
- [Generator docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/generator.html)
- [BitGenerator docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html)
- [Developer's github](https://github.com/bashtage/randomgen)

Comment: Any luck / yet!?

Comment: @jtlz2 wish i could say yes

Answer (score 2):

As of numpy version 1.23, they list 9 differences at [What’s New or Different](https://numpy.org/doc/1.23/reference/random/new-or-different.html). To better understand the logic behind the change, I'd recommend reading [NEP 19](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html)

TLDR:

1. API changes "cleaned up"
2. Performance changes, mostly due to switching from Box-Muller to Ziggurat algorithms it seems. Some go to 4x faster with the new approach. See [Performance](https://numpy.org/doc/1.23/reference/random/performance.html)
3. Numba and Cython compatible BitGenerators.
4. New `dtype`, `out` and `axis` arguments to fill parts of existing arrays and to control output datatypes.

Comment: whoa, numba compatible BitGenerators. I wonder if anything works with jax, too?